# addFieldtofilter array not reading

Tags: product-attribute, collection, product-collection, array

I am trying to filter product collection by ids if I use below code, the filter works ok and the product shows.

```
$this->_productCollection
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=> 460 ));
```

The problem is that if I set an array to this code and try to filter, I keep getting empty collection.

```
$getData = array(460);
$this->_productCollection
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=> $getData ));
```

I've already tried setting array like the following

```
$getData[$a]= array(460);
```

and reading like

```
array('in'=> $getData[$a] )
```

PS: My array is variable, not only one product
I can't see anything wrong with the code and if dump array it is ok I think: array([0] => int(460))

Comment: Well, I was placing the code below this: $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory()); if ($origCategory) { $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory); } } after placing the code before this lines it works weirdly, if someone can explain, I will accept as answer.

Comment: Please share your full collection code. Are you having this on Magento 2?

Comment: Please check that `460` is product's ID or category's ID.

Comment: It is product ID, and on magento 1.9.3. Please check my comment, any info?

Comment: Ok, try my code and let me know if it is working for you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$getData= array(17,78);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=> $getData ));
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

**You were doing the filter after category filter,so it may be that product is not in current category.That why your collection was returning Null.** .

Better way to filter by product ids is

```
$productIDS =  array(460,4,98);
$collection->addIdFilter($productIDS);
```

Comment: the products are in the category. it is like the code was not accepting an array of values after those lines of code. Check my comment.